# Rep point gained on question for no apparent reason

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I seem to have gained one reputation point on this question, for no apparent reason:

[NSOperation vs Grand Central Dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373331/nsoperation-vs-grand-central-dispatch)

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: I assume you downvoted a question on that post

Comment: ...which was probably this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10373781/19679 that was deleted two days ago.

Comment: Yes. It's beacause you have downvoted on th post and that post has been removed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Comment: Weird that it didn't record that in your reputation history...

Comment: Thanks, possibly I did downvote an answer on that question from the review queue, but as @animuson says, it's not appearing on my rep history.

Comment: @Luke Do you have "show removed posts" enabled at the bottom? Maybe it just doesn't show it to moderators since it involved a downvote.

Comment: @animuson: are deletion 'vote rebalancing' entries visible to mods normally? If so, do mods have an option to toggle the 'show removed posts' checkbox too?

Comment: @Martijn I have a hunch that the downvoted and undownvoted events are hidden from moderators to preserve user anonymity. Other removal and reversal events are normally shown. And moderators only get that show/hide option on their own profiles. I'm not sure if it affects other profiles, though. I always have it on.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I assume he downvoted *an answer* and not *a question* on that post. :)

Comment: @animuson - yes, I have the 'show removed posts' box checked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that would cause such a rep change would be that you had previously downvoted an answer on the question, which would have cost 1 rep.

When an answer is deleted, all points gained or lost by users on it are refunded - in this case, you lost 1 rep on it by down voting, and the +1 is your refund.